# PHP Array duplicates: every string key has numeric key

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, json, pdo

I'm trying to get an array with utf-8 values from an MS-SQL query.

Nearly everything works fine, except that the result array looks like this:

```
Array (
 [id] => 1;
 [0] => 1; // this is redundant
 [countryName] => england;
 [1] => england; // this is redundant
)
```

I don't want the duplicate numeric keys. Why are they even created? The code which is leading to this result is:

```
# execute the query
foreach ($pdoConnection->query($sqlStatement) as $row) {
   // encode row in utf8 so json works and save row in array
   $output[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}
```

Thanks for any idea how that can be solved.

Comment: try to `var_dump` row and see what comes in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch as `associative`. Follow this example:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT title, FMarticle_id FROM articles WHERE domain_name =:domain_name');
$stmt->bindValue(':domain_name', $domain);
$stmt->execute();
$article_list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Reference: [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#116347)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line,

```
foreach ($pdoConnection->query($sqlStatement, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
```

That flag is for getting associative records.